# Regenerate certificate with another common name

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, x509, pki

I have private key (.key) and certificate (.pem)  from let's encrypt for my website what I want is to regenerate certificate with another common name and assign that certificate to let's encrypt key file that I already have it. is there any way to do that.. well browser detect that certificate from unknown authority or error in common name.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: FYI... Host names ***do not*** go in the *Common Name (CN)*; they go int the *Subject Alternative Name (SAN)*.  Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) It provides a lot of background information on X.509 server certificates, how to present names, and where the various rules come from.